# Shell ("cmd / c md ") not functioning in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm at a loss where to start to fix the issue.  I use this once a year, and it worked just fine last year.  This year  I have the following chart of dates that I convert to folder names, i.e. *X:\Loan Committee\Boardpaq\2022\01-2022\01-05-22*.  The code I used is below, It's getting caught at the Shell line, and I have no idea why.  Thanks in advance!

[image: Dates Sheet]

```
Public Sub Boardpaq()
    Dim objCol As Range, objCell As Range, strFolders As String

    For Each objCol In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:L5").Columns
        For Each objCell In objCol.Cells
            strFolders = "X:\Loan Committee\Boardpaq\" & Format(objCell, "yyyy")
            strFolders = strFolders & "\" & Format(objCell, "mm-yyyy") & "\" & Format(objCell, "mm-dd-yy")
            Shell ("cmd /c md " & Chr(34) & strFolders & Chr(34))
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mkdir-statement?

Comment: Alternatively, you can also do [FileSystemObject.CreateFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createfolder-method) using the `FileSystemObject` object.

Comment: I suppose that "X:" is a mapped drive on another computer/server. If so, you have to check  if `strFolders` root is available/accessible on the network, credentials have been changed, your computer is connected to the respective network and so on...

Comment: @GSerg, thanks I was able to use a few imbedded if statements and it fixed the issue.  If you want to pose your comment into an answer, I can give you the reputation.